# Display the strings inside the manipulate

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, manipulate

```
Rth[tmax_, tin_, qmax_] := N[(tmax - tin)/qmax];Phex[qmax_, m_, tamb_] := N[qmax/(((qmax/(m*0.063*4184)) - tamb) - tamb)]Manipulate[StringJoin["CP Thermal Resistance:", "HEX Performance:" ToString[Style[Rth[tmax, tin, qmax], 14]]],StringJoin["HEX Performance:",ToString[Style[Phex[qmax, m, tamb], 14]]],Delimiter,Text[Style["Performance Calculator", 20, Background -> LightBlue,FontWeight -> Bold]],Delimiter,{{tmax, 100, "Max Cold-Plate Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7},{{qmax, 1000, "Heat Load (W): "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 7},{{tin, 30, "Cold-Plate Inlet Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, 
 {{m, 0.5, "Flow Rate (GPM): "}, ControlType -> InputField,FieldSize -> 7},{{tamb, 25, "Ambient air Temperature (\[Degree]C): "},ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7},Delimiter, Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}],Background -> Blue], LabelStyle -> {16},ContentSize -> 300,TrackedSymbols :> All]
```

I want display the value of Rth & Phex as an output. but i dont know what mistake i am doing here.

Answer (score 5):

You had few syntax errors. Try this. Also, the Manipulate expression needs to be a single expression. Not things separated by commas as you had it. So  I put it inside a `Row` for now.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Rth[tmax_, tin_, qmax_] := N[(tmax - tin)/qmax];
Phex[qmax_, m_, tamb_] := 
 N[qmax/(((qmax/(m*0.063*4184)) - tamb) - tamb)]

Manipulate[
 Row[{
   StringJoin["CP Thermal Resistance:", "HEX Performance:", 
    ToString[Style[Rth[tmax, tin, qmax], 14]]], 
   StringJoin["HEX Performance:", 
    ToString[Style[Phex[qmax, m, tamb], 14]]],
   Text[Style["Performance Calculator", 20, Background -> LightBlue, 
     FontWeight -> Bold]]
   }],
 Delimiter,
 
 {{tmax, 100, "Max Cold-Plate Temperature (\[Degree]C): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{qmax, 1000, "Heat Load (W): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{tin, 30, 
   "Cold-Plate Inlet Temperature (\[Degree]C): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{m, 0.5, "Flow Rate (GPM): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, 
  FieldSize -> 7}, {{tamb, 25, 
   "Ambient air Temperature (\[Degree]C): "}, 
  ControlType -> InputField, FieldSize -> 7}, Delimiter, 
 Item[Button["Calculate", Nothing, BaseStyle -> {15}], 
  Background -> Blue], LabelStyle -> {16},
 
 ContentSize -> 300,
 TrackedSymbols :> All
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks For your support.. Can we make a put box to display the values as input box?

Comment: @ASHISH You can use `Grid` instead of `Row` to have more control of your final output appearance.  Look at help for Grid. There many examples there. Use `Framed` option and `Spacing` option to adjust spacing as needed.

Comment: I did but not working for me... Can we make a dialog box as input same for to display the Rth & Phex values?

Comment: I want to display the output more attractive.. do you have any idea how we can do that... Remove this performance calculator text box..

Comment: @ASHISH How you want to display the output is your design decision as I do not know how you want it to look like. As I said, I use Grid for my main layout. Just replace Row with Grid. You could look for examples at [demonstrations.wolfram.com](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/?source=nav)